# How to declare a pointer to member template function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, member, declare

```
struct S
{
    template <auto> void F(){};
};

S s;
void (S::* pmf)()=s.F<true>;
```

**compiles error, how to fix it?
Thanks for your help.**

Comment: Can you please add the error that you get. Which compiler did you used ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the class name to qualify the member function, and there's no implicit conversion from member function to member function pointer, so use `operator&` explicitly. e.g.

```
void (S::* pmf)() = &S::F<true>;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oiZ1ZV4fq3wBKKxq)

Comment: Hi, I modify the problem extend it to member of pointer to member stuff. Do you know how to fix nested pointer-to-member itself m_pmd/m_pmf problem?

Comment: @Larry It seems to be a new question; I sugguest posting a new one instead of modifying this one.

Comment: ok, repost it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726320/how-to-declare-a-member-pointer-to-member-stuff-m-pmd-m-pmf-and-access-them