# How to declare a member pointer to member stuff m_pmd/m_pmf and access them?

Tags: c++

```
struct S
{
    template <auto> void F(){};
    int i;
    int S::* m_pmd; //compiles ok
    void (S::* m_pmf) (); //compiles ok
};

S s;
void (S::* pmf)()=&S::F<true>;
(s.*pmf)(); //pmf call ok
int S::* pmd=&S::i;
s.*pmd =123; //pmd call ok

s.m_pmd=&S::i; // compiles ok
s.m_pmf=&S::F<123>; //compiles ok

//now the problem occurred ... ?
s.*m_pmd; //error...?
s.*m_pmf; //error...?
```

First can declare pmd/pmf outside of type S and access it through s.*....

But, if we declare pmd/pmf inside of type itself, how to access them?

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the same rules recursively.

You already know (and showed) that to invoke `mfptr` on `obj`, you do `(obj.*mfptr)()`.

Now you want to invoke `s.m_pmf` on `s` (presumably).

So:

```
s.*(s.m_pmd);
(s.*(s.m_pmf))();
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e90357a5bd23455))

Yuck. Perhaps use some nice lambdas instead?